# Scrapy in threaded environment in python

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy in a threaded environment - see here:

GetJob.py

```
class Job():    
    def getJobs(self):
        mysql = MysqlConnector.Mysql()
        db = mysql.getConnection();
        cur = db.cursor();
        cur.execute("SELECT *  FROM job WHERE status=0 OR days>0")
        print "Get new jobs"
        #JobModel        
        joblist=[]
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            job = JobModel.JobModel();
            job.id = row[0]
            job.user_id = row[1]
            job.name = row[2]
            job.url = row[3]
            job.api = row[4]
            job.max_pages = row[5]
            job.crawl_depth = row[6]
            job.processing_patterns = row[7]
            job.status = row[8]
            job.days = row[9]
            joblist.append(job);

        #Proces the job now
        for job in joblist:
            processJob = ProcessJob.ProcessJob();
            th=Thread(target=processJob.processJob,args=(job,))
            th.daemon=True
            th.start();

        db.close()
```

ProcessJob.py

```
class ProcessJob():
    def processJob(self, job):
        #update job
        mysql = MysqlConnector.Mysql()
        db = mysql.getConnection();
        cur = db.cursor(); 
        job.status = 1
        update = "UPDATE job SET status=1 WHERE id=" + str(job.id)
        cur.execute(update)
        db.commit()
        db.close()

        runner = CrawlerRunner()
        d = runner.crawl(spider.MySpider)
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()
```

When i execute this i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 417, in fireEvent
    DeferredList(beforeResults).addCallback(self._continueFiring)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 317, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 306, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 430, in _continueFiring
    callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1189, in _reallyStartRunning
    self._handleSignals()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 295, in _handleSignals
    _SignalReactorMixin._handleSignals(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1154, in _handleSignals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigInt)
exceptions.ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

What i'm doing is following:

Get Jobs retrieves new jobs from the database (so new crawljobs).
If a job has status of 0 (means awaiting process) it will be given to ProcessJob -> ProcessJob then should start the crawler. I actually can't link the MySpider (cause of SO limitations) but the Spider works when i start it on the main thread.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
reactor.run(0)
# This will turn off signals
```